# Unexplained logging issue during JMeter load testing

Tags: java, log4j, jmeter

I am performing load testing of the media server with JMeter. I've wrote custom sampler that extends `AbstractJavaSamplerClient`. For the logging I'm using log4j (only one rootCategory appender is used ).

- When the number of threads in the thread group is relatively small (less then 800) - all works fine.
- When the number of threads in the thread group is relatively big (greater then 1400) - some unexplained logging issue is occurred.

Two cases can be considered. In the first case `ConsoleAppender` is used, in the second case - `FileAppender`.

- In the first case, log file is terminated abruptly. However test-plan is executed successfully and JMeter log (jmeter.log) also terminates fine. There is no exception thrown.
- In the second case log file is also terminated abruptly, but the reason of it is understandable:

  ```
  log4j:ERROR Failed to flush writer,java.io.IOException: File too large
      at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
      at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:318)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
      at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
      at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
      at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
      at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
      at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
      at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
      at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
      at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)
      at com.nsacdn.common.AbstractHTTPDownloader.downloadChunk(Unknown Source)
      at com.nsacdn.common.AbstractHTTPDownloader.downloadAllChunks(Unknown Source)
      at com.nsacdn.hls.HlsDownloader.download(Unknown Source)
      at com.nsacdn.common.DownloadSampler.runTest(Unknown Source)
      at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:191)
      at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:428)
      at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
  ```

However size of the log file is quite small - less then 10 M. There is more then enough free space on the hard drive. I am running tests on Ubuntu 12.04 x64. There are no limitations on file size in the `/etc/security/limits.conf` (by default there are no limitations of file size in this OS as I understand).

I've tried to simulate logging process. I've written simple app which creates 2000 parallel threads that totally write about 70 M in the log using same log4j configurations. This app works fine on the target machine.

Finally I've replaced `FileAppender` with `RollingFileAppender` and set limit on the log file size to 2 M. In this case logging process is performed correctly.

How the strange behavior of the ConsoleAppender and FileAppender can be explained?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I would check the log file for the JMeter application itself.  JMeter has the log files that it uses to log the information (from the listeners) and JMeter has a file for logging information from the application.  In the version 2.9 it can be found at

install directory/bin/jmeter.log

You might have been doing something that was just pumping out errors.